# damaged large file transfer

Tags: java, sockets, client-server

When I try to send a large file from server by splitting it, some of the packages don't arrive at the client... as you can see in the console output

http://s7.postimg.org/94yjfame3/error.png

the client receive only 19799.. bytes , and the server sent 62800.. bytes.

the code is too long to past here... but here are the basics:

```
// server side -> send data

BufferedOutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

byte[] somePackageInfo= new byte[500];
byte[] streamOut = new byte[20000];

while(getDataFromLargeFile(somePackageInfo,streamOut) != 0) {

  out.write(somePackageInfo,0,500);
  out.write(streamOut);
  out.flush();

}

out.write(0);
out.flush();


// client side -> get data

BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

byte[] somePackageInfo= new byte[500];
byte[] streamIn= new byte[20000];

while(true) {

  if(in.read(somePackageInfo,0,500) == 0) break;
  in.read(streamIn);
  saveDataToLargeFile(somePackageInfo,streamIn);
}
```

I tried to slow down the transfer (`sleep(500)`)  but only **most** of the packages arrived.

tried to remove the `flush()` but still only **most** of the packages arrived.

what causes this problem  and how can i fix it?

Comment: Show your `getData()` and `saveDataToLargeFile` methods.

Comment: i dont think this is the problem.. those methods read/write data to a file.

Comment: Probably incorrectly if your file is corrupt.

Comment: i know for sure that those functions works correctly, and the file isn't corrupted.

Answer (score 1):

Your copy code is wrong. You are ignoring the count returned by read, and assuming that it fills the buffer. It isn't required to do that. See the Javadoc.

```
while ((count = in.read(buffer)) > 0)
{
    out.write(buffer, 0, count);
}
```

Use with any buffer size greater than zero, typically 8192. Use at both ends.

Adding sleeps is literally a waste of time.

Comment: I don't think you can have read what I wrote with sufficient attention. Try again